# socket.io starts and stops again immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm playing around with node.js and socket.io. I have to files:

Server-side:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)
var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connect', function (client) {
    console.log('Client connected');
    client.emit('messages', {hello: "hello"});
});
```

Client-side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
var server = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
server.on('messages', function(data){
    alert(data.hello);
});
</script>
```

When i type `node <name-of-my-file>` this happens:

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using expressjs but you did not set it to listen to any port.

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)
app.listen(8000);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Comment: silly me... Thank you! Quick question though: Now it says 'Cannot GET /' when i go to 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @Nilzone- Socket.IO only responds to a limited set of URL paths. So, you'll need to establish that with Express. You can [`.use()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) the `express.static()` middleware to serve files from a particular directory, including an `index.html`. Or [create a route](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) with `app.get('/', ...)`.